# ionic windows-cordova running windows universal app in an emulator

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to deploy my **ionic application** in a **windows 10 emulator**.

I have added **windows platform**.

I have setted `windows-target-version` to `10.0` by adding this tag to the **config.xml** file of the application.

```
  <platform name="windows">
      <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  </platform>
```

I am using Windows 10 and I have properly installed **Windows 10 SDK**.

When I target the emulator, by running `C:\Users\YBoukhata\labs\ap1>cordova run windows -- --phone`, get this error

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: TypeError: Cannot read property '__ip' of undefined
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

#### For me details, here the full console messages

```
C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1>cordova run windows  -- --phone
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1
add to body class: platform-windows
Building project: C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : anycpu
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug.
  appx
Deploying windows10 package to device:
C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug.appx
Attempting to remove previously installed application...
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: TypeError: Cannot read property '__ip' of undefined
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

#### Installed Emulators

```
C:\Users\yacine\labs\ap1>cordova run windows --list
Available windows devices:
0. Device (device)
Available windows virtual devices:
1. Emulator 10.0.1.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB (emulator)
2. Emulator 10.0.1.0 WVGA 4 inch 1GB (emulator)
3. Emulator 10.0.1.0 WXGA 4.5 inch 1GB (emulator)
4. Emulator 10.0.1.0 720p 5 inch 1GB (emulator)
5. Emulator 10.0.1.0 1080p 6 inch 2GB (emulator)
```

Any help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By debugging **windows cordova plugin**, I realized that emulation in windows 10 is not supported yet. By default, it launch deployment in devices.

When I force emulation in the option parameters, I get this warning

```
Windows 10 Phone emulator is currently not supported. 
If you want to deploy to emulator, please use Visual Studio instead.

Attempting to deploy to device...
```